# Enable built-in Microsoft Word button controls with Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word

Tags: c#, ms-word, vsto, ms-office

I am currently in the need to compare two Microsoft Word documents with `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word`. I've found the [`Application.CompareDocument`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/microsoft.office.interop.word._application.comparedocuments.aspx) method, which does exactly what I want. The following C# source code (snippet) compares a document saved in the filesystem with the current active document and opens the result in a new document:

```
using Word = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;

// [...]

Word.Document originalDocument = this.application.Documents.Open(filePath, ReadOnly: true, Visible: false);
Word.Document diffDocument = this.application.CompareDocuments(
    originalDocument,
    this.application.ActiveDocument);
((Word._Document)originalDocument).Close(SaveChanges: false);

// TODO Activate two built-in Microsoft Word buttons.

// [...]
```

**But** I also need to activate two built-in buttons in the view of the newly created Word document. After searching on MSDN for a while, I am unable to find a way to achieve what I want. I've added two screenshots to this question, which display the built-in buttons I want to activate (sadly, I am using the German version of Microsoft Word 2010, so I don't know what the exact translations are).

1. "Quelldokumente anzeigen" (could be translated as "Display source documents"). I need to activate the button "Beide anzeigen" (could be translated as "Display both").
   [image: Screenshot of the button Quelldokumente anzeigen]
2. "Überarbeitungsbereich" (could be translated as "Revision pane"). I need to activate the button "Überarbeitungsbereich vertikal..." (could be translated as "Vertical revision pane...").
   [image: Screenshot of the button Überarbeitungsbereich]

To conclude, I want to know how I can modifiy the state (either directly or indirectly via an method call) of these two buttons.

**EDIT (2013-08-03)**

The revisions pane can be set via the following method:

```
diffDocument.ActiveWindow.View.SplitSpecial = Word.WdSpecialPane.wdPaneRevisionsVert;
```

I am still searching for a solution to display both the source document and revised document panes.

**EDIT (2013-08-05)**

The show source documents button can be modified to show both source documents via the following method:

```
diffDocument.ActiveWindow.ShowSourceDocuments = Word.WdShowSourceDocuments.wdShowSourceDocumentsBoth;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possible solutions of your problems:

<strike>**Ad 1.** but first, you need to open your documents with `ReadOnly: false` while,according to both C# and VBA test it will not work when you set parameters to `ReadOnly: true`:</strike>

<strike>`((Word._Document)diffDocument).Windows.CompareSideBySideWith(originalDocument);`</strike>

**Ad 2.** this time you need to refer to window object of Word Application. Here is code for active window:

```
appWRD.ActiveWindow.View.SplitSpecial = Word.WdSpecialPane.wdPaneRevisionsVert;
```

where: `appWRD` is `Word.Application` in my code.

**Ad 1 again.** (one above was a result of misunderstanding).

According to some test this code should give you what you need:

```
appWRD.ActiveWindow.ShowSourceDocuments = Word.WdShowSourceDocuments.wdShowSourceDocumentsBoth;
```

Comment: Ad 2. does exactly want I want with the revisions pane. But Ad 1. does something completely different: It shows the documents in the so-called "side-by-side" view. That is different from the functionality behind the button "Compare source documents", e.g. when clicking "Original anzeigen" (engl. "Show original"), a new task pane inside the current window is displayed. Maybe there is another View method to do that, but I couldn't find it yet.

Comment: @FlorianWolters, I'll check it again a bit later or...on Monday :)